# Combine 2 picture boxes into a new picture box

Tags: vb.net

I have my pixBox1 which is fix, and unable to change the image

and pixBox2 is not fix which can change there color and rotate in here

i use OpenFileDialog function to put image inside those pixbox

so now how can i combine those two pixbox into my pixbox3?

i try this but it doesn't look like it's going to work:

```
  Dim image As New Bitmap(pixBox1.Image)
    Dim image2 As New Bitmap(pixBox2.Image)
    Dim Image3 As New Bitmap(300, 300)

    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(Image3)

    g.DrawImage(image1, New Point(300, 300))

    g.DrawImage(image2, New Point(300, 300))

    g.Dispose()

    g = Nothing

    pixBox3.Image = Image3
```

Comment: What do you mean by combine? Attach side by side? Overlay with some sort of color mixing? Overlay with transparency?

Comment: Don't draw the image at (300, 300), that draws it outside of the bitmap.  Draw at (0, 0) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kinda ugly and slow, but it basically sets all the pixels in `image2` to be 50% transparent then draws it over the top of `Image`.

```
Dim image As New Bitmap(pixBox1.Image)
Dim image2 As New Bitmap(pixBox2.Image)
Dim Image3 As New Bitmap(300, 300)

Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(Image3)

    'make 2nd bmp translucent

    For Integer Xcount = 0 To image2.Width - 1            
        For Integer Ycount = 0 To image2.Height - 1
            Dim c as Color = image2.GetPixel(Xcount, Ycount)
            c = Color.FromARGB(125, c.R, c.G, c.B) '50% alpha
            image2.SetPixel(Xcount, Ycount, c)
        Next 
    Next 

    g.DrawImage(image1, New Point(0, 0))

    g.DrawImage(image2, New Point(0, 0))

End Using

pixBox3.Image = Image3
```

As a side note, the `Using` block makes sure `g` is disposed no matter what happens.